# PHP/Mysql syntax error with insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Can someone tell me where I'm wrong with my request?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO order (order_id,prod) VALUES ('','".$prod."')";
mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());
$_SESSION['orderid']=mysql_insert_id();
```

Here is my table configuration:

Columns for `order` table:

```
'order_id'=>int(11) auto_increment
'prod'=> varchar(20) utf8_general_ci
```

And this is the error message:

> Error SQL !INSERT INTO order (order_id,prod) VALUES ('','xxx')
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server         version for the right syntax to use near 'order (order_id,prod) VALUES ('','xxx')' at line 1

Thank you

Comment: Please look into PDO or MySQLi for database handling. MySQL is deprecated now

Comment: Also, posting the value of $prod will help :)

Comment: it is posted in the error message (that is: xxx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved keyword and happens to be the name of your column/table. To avoid syntax error, you need to escape it using backtick. E.g.

```
`ORDER`
```

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

If you have the privilege to alter the table, change the table name to which is not a reserved keyword to avoid problem from occurring again.

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (order_id,prod) VALUES ('','".$prod."')
```

Answer (score 1):

replace with this, just use single quote with table name

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order` (order_id,prod) VALUES ('','".$prod."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

$insert="INSERT INTO `order` (`order_id`,`prod`) VALUES ('','".$prod."')";